# Data written on Linux pipe by program 1 is sometimes read twice by program 2

Tags: c++, c, linux, pipe

I'm trying to establish an inter process communication on Linux using named pipes. At first glance my code seems to work, but I noticed that sometimes data written to the pipe by the "main" process is read twice by the "child" process (in fact it's two separate programs).

Program 1 (write only, starts first) is a legacy program. The below code is implemented in a onclick-function for a button on a GUI. When I press the button the data string shall be sent via pipe to another program. Code:

main.h

```
const char * FSCpipe = "/tmp/fscpipe";
int counter = 1;
```

main()

```
::mkfifo(FSCpipe, 0666);
```

OnClick-Function

```
QString data = "179.45";
int fd;
char msg[10];

fd = ::open(FSCpipe, O_WRONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
    msg[i] = data.at(i).toLatin1();
}
msg[data.length()] = '\0';
::write(fd, msg, strlen(msg)+1);
::close(fd);
qDebug() << QString("Counter: %1").arg(counter);
counter++;
```

Program 2 (only read, starts second) is started in a new terminal. Code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{    
   int fd;
   const char * FSCpipe = "/tmp/fscpipe";
   char data[10];
   size_t nbytes;
   nbytes = sizeof(data);
   while(1) {
      fd = open(FSCpipe, O_RDONLY);
      ssize_t bytesread = read(fd, data, nbytes);
      printf("received: %s\n", data);
      close(fd);
      printf("Counter: %d ", counter);
      printf("chars: %d\n", bytesread);
      counter++;
   }
   return(0);
}
```

Sometimes I noticed a strange behaviour, feeling like there is more data read then written. So I implemented independent counter in both programs. When I press the button in program 1, the data is send via the pipe and the counter increments. When program 2 receives and outputs the data in the terminal, its counter is also incremented. After some clicks on the button in program 1, I can see a higher counter value in program 2, indicating that it reads more often then program 1 writes. Why is that ?

Apart from that, the data string should contain special characters encoded in UTF-8, like this:

```
QString data = "197,45 \xc2\xb5m";
```

How should I convert the string to send it correctly via pipe?

Thank you for helping me!

Comment: You don't do any error checking.

Comment: You also fail to terminate the data in `msg` with a `'\0' char` value before treating it as a C-style string with `strlen()`.

Comment: @Galik Yes, I would add this when I have a working code framework.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yes, but as I read here [link](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/library-function/string.h/strlen) it would not make a difference? Anyway I tried it with a terminating `'\0' char` but it's the same behaviour as explained above.

Comment: Why wouldn't it make a difference?  A C string is ***defined*** as `char` values terminated with a `'\0'` character value.   When you leave that termination off, you invoke undefined behavior because without that termination **it's not a string** and that link doesn't apply - `strlen()` only calculates the length of a string.

Comment: [read](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) might not read 10 bytes, you should check the return value

Comment: You should add the error checking first because it might tell you, or give you a clue what is going wrong.

Comment: In fact *every time* you write the code to call a function you should *also* write the code to check for any errors that calling the function may have produced.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I added a byte counter in program 2. `read()` returns 7 bytes for the given data string in program 1. However it returns 0 when it comes to those mysterious double readings.

Comment: You must initialize `nbytes` to the size of data before reading.

Comment: @JuanR Yes, I forgot to edit it in. It's fixed now, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: `0` means end of file, as nothing has been read the buffer is unchanged so printing it will give duplicate data

Comment: @AlanBirtles Ok, but why is `read()` sometimes triggered a second time? I only do one click, but sometimes I get two data outputs.

Comment: If you check the return value for errors you may find it tells you what is wrong. Try `if(bytesread == -1) printf("error: %s", strerror(errno));` It is a good idea to read the manual about the returned errors, particularly when you have non-blocking input: https://linux.die.net/man/2/read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some helpful information [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html), stating:

> "If all file descriptors referring to the write end of a pipe have been closed, then an attempt to read(2) from the pipe will see end-of-file (read(2) will return 0)"

I took out `fd = ::open(...);` and `::close(fd);` from my onclick-function in program 1 and put them into the mainwindow-constructor and the mainwindow-close-function respectively. So the write end is always opened and program 2 works as intended.

Thank you all for your help.